# MSpec & Resharper test runner issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, bdd, mspec

I'm using MSpec and Visual Studio 2010 with Resharper 5.1. I've installed the MSpec test runner plugin into resharper but it's not working properly. Here's my test:

```
    public class when_I_click_create_investment_manager : with_main_window
    {
        Establish I_am_viewing_the_main_page = () => mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
        Because the_user_clicks_create = () => mainWindowViewModel.CreateInvestmentManager.Execute(null);
        It should_show_the_investment_manager_details_screen = () => mainWindowViewModel.CurrentWorkspace.ShouldBeOfType(typeof(IInvestmentManagerDetailsViewModel));
        It should_set_the_edit_screen_to_create_mode = () => mainWindowViewModel.CurrentWorkspace.Mode.ShouldEqual(WorkspaceMode.New);  
    }

    public class with_main_window
    {
        protected static IMainWindowViewModel mainWindowViewModel;
    }
```

But the test runner doesn't run my asserts but still shows success, the output I get is:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issues are very likely caused by an outdated build of the MSpec plugin + assembly in your project directory. Please make sure you have the latest build of [MSpec from CodeBetter CI](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/project.html?projectId=project27) both in the ReSharper plugin directory and your project.

Comment: Thanks you were right. My spec project was referencing v0.2 and it needed v0.3.

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same problem with the latest version

Comment: Please make sure your project's MSpec assembly matches the one in the ReSharper plugin directory.